# Bootstrap 3 css conflicts inside IE8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, windows-xp

I was wondering if anyone has ever had issues with using the source code version of Bootstrap 3 inside IE8 XP?

Basically the source code has jumbotron.less, thumbnails.less, alerts.less...etc...

If I comment out jumbotron.less so it won't be compiled to css, the site renders correctly on IE8, but if I keep jumbotron.less, it breaks the site even though I am not using jumbotron classes inside the website at all.

For ex: (This is the current jumbotron.less file)

```
//
// Jumbotron
// --------------------------------------------------
.jumbotron {
  padding: @jumbotron-padding;
  margin-bottom: @jumbotron-padding;
  color: @jumbotron-color;
  background-color: @jumbotron-bg;

  h1,
  .h1 {
    color: @jumbotron-heading-color;
  }
  p {
    margin-bottom: (@jumbotron-padding / 2);
    font-size: @jumbotron-font-size;
    font-weight: 200;
  }

  .container & {
    border-radius: @border-radius-large; 
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    padding-top:    (@jumbotron-padding * 1.6);
    padding-bottom: (@jumbotron-padding * 1.6);

    .container & {
      padding-left:  (@jumbotron-padding * 2);
      padding-right: (@jumbotron-padding * 2);
    }

    h1,
    .h1 {
      font-size: (@font-size-base * 4.5);
    }
  }
}
```

It will get compiled into css like this below:

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.jumbotron h1,
.jumbotron .h1 {
  color: inherit;
}
.jumbotron p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.container .jumbotron {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
  }
  .container .jumbotron {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  .jumbotron h1,
  .jumbotron .h1 {
    font-size: 63px;
  }
}
```

From what I can tell, if I don't use any .jumbotron classes inside my website, this should not affect the site rendering...but currently it does.

Even if I remove the contents of the css, it still affects the layout...
e.g.

```
.jumbotron {

}
.jumbotron h1,
.jumbotron .h1 {

}
.jumbotron p {

}
.container .jumbotron {

}
.jumbotron .container {

}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron {

  }
  .container .jumbotron {

  }
  .jumbotron h1,
  .jumbotron .h1 {

  }
}
```

The only way to fix this is to comment out the jumbotron.less file so it doesn't get compiled to css.

I'm currently stuck right now and was wondering if anyone has ever had any issues like this.

Currently this only affects people on IE8 on XP

I have commented out

```
-//@import "../less/jumbotron.less";
-//@import "../less/thumbnails.less";
-//@import "../less/alerts.less";
-//@import "../less/progress-bars.less";
-//@import "../less/media.less";
-//@import "../less/list-group.less";
-//@import "../less/panels.less";
-//@import "../less/wells.less";
-//@import "../less/close.less";
```

because they are currently causing issues inside IE8.

Comment: What kinds of things change in IE8 specifically when you exclude jumbotron?

Comment: What specific version of Bootstrap are you using? v3.1.1?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.1.1. The styling of the autocomplete box is broken when I include jumbotron. Eg. When you type something into a input box, a drop down list shows up and shows an autocomplete box. I'm currently using "http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/" to create this autocomplete box

Comment: possible duplicate of [Less mixin generate error on IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351645/less-mixin-generate-error-on-ie8)